# Is there a way to influence how user voice input is interpreted?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We have an Acton on Google where a user needs to say one of these answers: 'High', 'Rising', 'Low' or 'Falling'.

But when user says "high", it is often recognised as "hi", and "low" as "hello".

I found @Leon Nicholls uses speechBiasing here: https://github.com/entertailion/Magnificent-Escape-Action/blob/4258a544789624b82253b4d29355a7519aab4179/game.js

So I addeded this before doing onv.ask(...):

```
conv.speechBiasing = ['High', 'Rising', 'Low', 'Falling'];
```

This resulted in this:

> "speechBiasingHints": [
>           "High",
>           "Rising",
>           "Low",
>           "Falling"
>         ],

Unfortunately, the user answer is still showing on SmartScreen as "hi" and not "high".

Is there another way to influence how the user voice input is interpreted?

Comment: Can't you use an [entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-overview) for this?

Comment: @gmolau we do use an entity, but it comes later on. We want to influence ASR, not NLU.

Comment: Yes, but if you were using an entity to capture the answer the users input would only be matched against the four entity values, and you would be guaranteed to get exactly the spelling that you have set up. That would solve your problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: The problem is not in recognition, but in the interpretation of what user said. This problem is mitigated down the line, but since I'm providing speech biasing (not text biasing), I expect _speech_ to be recognized as "high".

Comment: Google recently introduced [Auto speech adaptation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/speech-adaptation) but unfortunately it doesn't work for Actions on Google.

Comment: Filip Kwiatkowski thank you for the info. This would be exactly what we need of it worked on AoG.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a specific intent to be selected as a response, you can use `possibleIntents: []` ([doc](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse)) in addition to `speechBiasingHints: []`.

You can also use follow-up intents as described [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reprompts). Note that although the implementation is done in Dialogflow in the documentation you can recreate the logic in code if you're not using Dialogflow.